# Can't convert string to float - Python Dash

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash

I'm trying to convert string into float in Dash callback but when I run my code I'm getting in my Dash app error: *lati = float(lati[-1])
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'float64)* I'm not getting this error in terminal though.

First what I need to do is extract given latitude (and longitude) number. Therefore I need it to convert it to string and split it because I could not find better way to get this number from csv file using pandas.

Output:

```
# converting to string:
12    41.6796
Name: latitude, dtype: float64

# splitting:
['12', '', '', '', '41.6796']

# converting to float:
41.6796
```

This is the actual code:

```
@app.callback(Output('text-output', 'children'),
    [Input('submit-val', 'n_clicks')],
    [State('search-input', 'value')])
def updateText(n_clicks, searchVar):
    df = pd.read_csv("powerplant.csv")
    df = df[df.name == searchVar]

    # converting to string
    lati = str(df['latitude'])
    longi = str(df['longitude'])

    # splitting it
    lati = lati.split('\n', 1)
    lati = lati[0].split(' ', 4)
    longi = longi.split('\n', 1)
    longi = longi[0].split(' ', 4)

    #converting to float
    lati = float(lati[-1])
    longi = float(longi[-1])
```

I actually tested this code in other script and it worked just fine. Is there any better way how could I extract latitude and longitude numbers?

The data can be downloaded from https://datasets.wri.org/dataset/globalpowerplantdatabase; here is an excerpt.

```
country,country_long,name,gppd_idnr,capacity_mw,latitude,longitude,primary_fuel,other_fuel1,other_fuel2,other_fuel3,commissioning_year,owner,source,url,geolocation_source,wepp_id,year_of_capacity_data,generation_gwh_2013,generation_gwh_2014,generation_gwh_2015,generation_gwh_2016,generation_gwh_2017,estimated_generation_gwh
AFG,Afghanistan,Kajaki Hydroelectric Power Plant Afghanistan,GEODB0040538,33.0,32.3220,65.1190,Hydro,,,,,,GEODB,http://globalenergyobservatory.org,GEODB,1009793,2017,,,,,,
AFG,Afghanistan,Mahipar Hydroelectric Power Plant Afghanistan,GEODB0040541,66.0,34.5560,69.4787,Hydro,,,,,,GEODB,http://globalenergyobservatory.org,GEODB,1009795,2017,,,,,,
ALB,Albania,Shkopet,WRI1002173,24.0,41.6796,19.8305,Hydro,,,,1963.0,,Energy Charter Secretariat,http://www.energycharter.org/fileadmin/DocumentsMedia/IDEER/IDEER-Albania_2013_en.pdf,GEODB,1021238,,,,,,,79.22851153039832
ALB,Albania,Ulez,WRI1002174,25.0,41.6796,19.8936,Hydro,,,,1958.0,,Energy Charter Secretariat,http://www.energycharter.org/fileadmin/DocumentsMedia/IDEER/IDEER-Albania_2013_en.pdf,GEODB,1021241,,,,,,,82.52969951083159
```

Comment: What do you get when you run this code but print the `lati[-1]` instead of trying to convert it....what is the output ? Do you get `41.6796` -exactly- or somethig different ? It seems that the csv rader did not convert your column properly...

Comment: Can you add a few example lines from `powerplant.csv`?

Comment: The error message suggests that you somehow end up processing the string `Name: latitude, dtype: float64`. It's not clear from your question where this comes from or how you could avoid it, but perhaps at least this will get you going in the right direction. Please [edit] to clarify if you still need help. Can you include a CSV snippet which exhibits this problem?

Comment: @yossefaz After submiting the name of the powerplant terminal is printing the correct number.

Comment: @tripleee Actually I get rid of this part Name: latitude, dtype: float64  after                2 step: ```1 step: 12    41.6796                                                                                             
Name: latitude, dtype: float64                                                                                                 
2 step: ['12    41.6796', 'Name: latitude, dtype: float64']                                             
3 step: ['12', '', '', '', '41.6796']                                                                                   
4 step: 41.6796 ```

Comment: I'm not a Pandas person but the motions you are going through seem quite insane. It should be trivial to extract a numeric column from CSV directly as a float.  It's not clear what your "steps" are; I guess you are printing debug output from your code, but not showing how you are doing that?

Comment: The download link you provided contains two lines which contain 41.6796 (I included them in the excerpt) but neither of them contains, or is adjacent to any other data which contains, the string 12. I'm flagging as unclear / unreproducible / needs debugging details.

Comment: @tripleee Well unfortunately it not possible to extract just the numeric value (latitude and longitude in my case) from pandas. I was looking everywhere for solution on how to do it but from what I learned it's not possible. Btw the number 12 is index which is automatically added to the output.

Comment: So it seems you are coercing a perfectly fine number into the Pandas `str` representation and then attempting to parse that? I repeat, this should absolutely not be necessary.

Comment: @tripleee Well if I print(df['latitude']) I'll get this output: "12    41.6796
Name: latitude, dtype: float64". As you can see you get lot of unneccesery data from reading csv using pandas. So I need to do all these steps to ged rif of them.

Comment: What you're looking at is a `Series` object. You need to call `.tolist()` if you want a list instead. Converting to a string to get the `__repr__` and then slicing it up is a really poor use of pandas

Comment: @roganjosh Ok that seems to be working fine :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the way you are accessing the values in a dataframe. Pandas allows you to access the data without having to parse the string representation.

You can access the row and the column in one call to `.loc`
If you know you will have a single value, you can call the `squeeze` method

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> # data shortened for brievity
>>> df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""country,country_long,name,gppd_idnr,capacity_mw,latitude,longitude
... AFG,Afghanistan,Kajaki Hydroelectric Power Plant Afghanistan,GEODB0040538,33.0,32.3220,65.1190
... AFG,Afghanistan,Mahipar Hydroelectric Power Plant Afghanistan,GEODB0040541,66.0,34.5560,69.4787
... ALB,Albania,Shkopet,WRI1002173,24.0,41.6796,19.8305
... ALB,Albania,Ulez,WRI1002174,25.0,41.6796,19.8936"""))
>>> searchVar = "Ulez"
>>> df.loc[df["name"] == searchVar, "latitude"] # here you have a pd.Series
3    41.6796
Name: latitude, dtype: float64
>>> df.loc[df["name"] == searchVar, "latitude"].squeeze() # here you have a scalar
41.6796
>>> df.loc[df["name"] == searchVar, "longitude"].squeeze()
19.8936
```

If for some reason you have several rows with the same name, you will get a Series back and not a scalar. But maybe it is a case where failure is what you want rather than passing ambiguous data.

Comment: Thank you. It works but I'm trying to convert those latitude and longitude numbers into float and then I'm getting an TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>                            `lati = df.loc[df["name"] == searchVar, "latitude"].squeeze()
loni = df.loc[df["name"] == searchVar, "longitude"].squeeze()`
                                                                                                                                            
`lati = float(lati)
loni = float(loni)`

Comment: Looks like you have several values with the same name. After `squeeze()` you should already have a float, unless there are several values, then you will have a Series

Comment: Yeah thats what I thought but here is the error: ValueError: 
    Invalid value of type 'pandas.core.series.Series' received for the 'lon' property of layout.mapbox.center
        Received value: Series([], Name: longitude, dtype: float64)

    The 'lon' property is a number and may be specified as:
      - An int or float

Comment: Seems like the problem is an empty Series. Are you sure your name is in the data frame? You need to handle this case in your function

Comment: Yeah youre right. Now it works as I want it to. Thank you very much. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking at is a `pandas.Series` object, containing a single row of data, and you're trying to chop up its `__repr__` to get at the value. There is no need for this. I'm not familiar with the Python version of plotly but I see that you have a callback so I've wrapped it up into a function (I'm not sure whether the case exists where the name can't be found):

```
import pandas as pd

def get_by_name(name):
    df = pd.read_csv('powerplants.csv')
    df = df[df['name'] == name]
    if not df.empty:
        return df[['latitude', 'longitude']].values.tolist()[0]
    return None, None


lat, lon = get_by_name('Kajaki Hydroelectric Power Plant Afghanistan')
```

Comment: @Michal that's not at all similar. My code is self-contained - all you need to do is change the name of the CSV